can i add only 1 field to unlocked package
I am starting to learn about unlocked packages. The question I have is if I have an app with a few classes and lwc components and just 1 field from Account object, can I create an unlocked package with just that 1 field or do I have to include Account object and all fields


Can I add only 1 field to an Unlocked Package?

Yes.
For any kind of package (Unmanaged Packages, First-Generation Managed Packages, Unlocked Packages, and Second-Generation Managed Packages), you can add just a single field from an object without adding all the fields on the object.
To do this, make sure that the field is the only field in the objects/Account/fields directory of your package source.
